# getLastNonConfigurationInstance always returning null

Tags: java, android, data-structures, object, hashmap

```
HashMap myMap = (HashMap) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

myMap is always null. getLastNonConfigurationInstance() returns an object. My map has two keys "symbol" and "name".

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
    {
        HashMap myMap = new HashMap();
        myMap.put("symbol", this.symbol);
        final Object data = myMap;
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: what about killing your "final" line and just doing "return myMap;"?  a HashMap is an Object after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` returns a non-null object, then `(HashMap) getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` will either return the same object (if that object is a `HashMap`), or throw a `ClassCastException`.

The situation that you describe is not possible, not unless you've uncovered a long-hidden bug in Java's cast operator.  Hint: you haven't.

Verify that `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` is actually returning a non-null object. Verify that `myMap` is actually null.  If you're using a debugger to check those values, try printing them to the console instead.  Debuggers can lie to you sometimes, or at least mislead.

Comment: I have updated my code to show onRetainNonConfigurationinstance()

Comment: @Sheehan - what's the relevance?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's returning null.

Comment: @Sheehan: are you saying that `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is the same as `getLastNonConfigurationInstance`? Why the different names? Is there a step in the middle there, that could be causing the problem?  Review the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: on the android platform, onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() saves some data, and to retrieve that saved data getLastNonConfigurationInstance() is called. The OS handles everything else inbetween.

Comment: @Sheehan: then something's going wrong in that middle step. What did you see when you printed the output of `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`?

Comment: @Sheehan: your issue is with the relevant API on the Android platform, not the Java language.  I think you'll get better help here if you rewrite your question around that.

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same issue. Looks like calling getLastNonConfigurationInstance() in anything other than onCreate() returns null. I moved the statement to onCreate() method and voila..it returned what I expected it to return.

Comment: I have used getLastNonConfigurationInstance() in OnCreateOptionsMenu() and it wasn't null

Comment: I'm calling a Loader on onCreate and by the time it comes back the value from getLastNonConfigurationInstance() is lost. So getting and retaining that value on onCreate is way to go

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us in what situation this happens? onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() is called before an Activity's onDestroy() when a configuration change happens.

Answer (score 0):

`getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` will return reference which was saved in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method.

`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method will be called between `onStop` and `onDestroy` is case of any configuration change, here you can save any Object reference.

Activity keeps this reference till `onResume` call.

```
Activity.class

final void performResume(boolean followedByPause, String reason) {
    ...
    mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null;       // clearing reference
    ...
    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnResume(this); // onResume
}
```