# getLastNonConfigurationInstance always returns null

Tags: android, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cast an object to a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640733/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-hashmap)

```
HashMap myMap = (HashMap) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

myMap is always null. getLastNonConfigurationInstance() should return an object.

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
    {
        HashMap myMap = new HashMap();
        myMap.put("symbol", this.symbol);
        final Object data = myMap;
        return data;
    }
```

Why is this?

Comment: In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640733/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-hashmap), I advised you to focus more on your issues with the Android API, and less on your assumptions about Java casting.  You haven't done that sufficiently here, and so you're not likely to get good answers.  You need to provide a lot more information. Talk about the relation between `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance` - how Android is supposed to get changes to the former from the latter.