# Dynamically added images are missing on device orientation in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, device-orientation

Below code is to create imageviews dynamically and add to its parent layout on click of a button. This works well. When i change the device orientation, everything is vanishing. i.e, After adding images if i change the device orientation the added images are missing. Why? How can i get back my images after changing the device orientation also?

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //create an imageview
    ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

    //set layout parameters
    img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

    //set image source
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);

    //add imageview to parent layout
    parentView.addView(img);        

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to affect the Layout then just add this tag to you xml file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

This will help in changing your layout but wont affect anyother thing.

```
  <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, still images are missing.

Comment: @user1129655 : try from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: if you are checking in emulator then android:configChanges="orientation" won't work. you should add keyboardHidden|orientation

Comment: @RaghuNagaraju: Okie. user1129655: try now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the bitmap is still lost. Including "screenSize" in the configChanges array seems to work, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can hanlde it by thises ways

1 - onSaveInstanceState() callback

ex: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)
    http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/onsaveinstancestate-and.html

2- onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() with  getLastNonConfigurationInstance()

ex: [getLastNonConfigurationInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994801/android-getlastnonconfigurationinstance)

3 - android:configChanges in menifest and orverirding onConfigChange in acivity
 ex:http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html
 [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

choose one way as per your need...

Comment: as per above description if image is need to restore then  2 option looks sufficient just get getLastNonConfigurationInstance() in onCreate, but not forgot null check.

Comment: http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/27/fighting-orientation-changes-in-android/