# getLastNonConfigurationInstance() substitute android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

When i use

```
  getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
```

The Eclipse IDE tells me that it is depreceated.Can anybody tell me the substitute of this method?

Comment: Java is case sensitive. You mean `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. (I know you wrote it correct in your code, but still).

Comment: yes.. any help?I was not able to understand from the android documentation about its substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)

> This method was deprecated in API level 13.
>   Use the new Fragment API setRetainInstance(boolean) instead

Comment: Read again what OP is asking. setRetainInstance(boolean) is the replacement for getLastNonConfigurationInstance() and onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). And yes the recommended way is to use fragments for obvious reasons like Designing for Multiple Screens: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: yes, its the replacement. if you're using fragments.

Comment: what is the replacement if you don't use fragments?